# Queryable object collection with O(1) lookup for members

Tags: c#, linq

I am in need of a generic collection that is able to store objects and query them in O(1) time based on their members. Consider the following class:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public readonly int Id;
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to store `MyObject` instances in the collection and be able to query objects by field/property using LINQ with (expected) O(1) lookup. Essentially, the values of the members would be keys to lists of matching objects.

An example usage might be:

```
var uniquePerson = collection.Query( x => x.Id == 10 ).First();
var peopleNamedTom = collection.Query( x => x.Name == "Tom" );
```

Does a collection like this exist? I'm guessing not, and will have to implement it myself, and it will involve a lot of reflection / dynamic IL. It would be much easier to just write a specialized collection that uses dictionaries for each property, but my goal is to have it as generic and reusable as possible.

Comment: How is finding an element in a collection (unsorted and with duplicates?) based on a condition like `id == 10` ever going to be O(1)? You need to check *all* items until you find a match and in the worst case there is no match, or you may get a match on the very last element.

Comment: Well a `Dictionary` is almost O(1) in performance (it uses a hash table internally), but that restricts you to using a single *unique* property (e.g. `Id` **or** `Name`). If you want to use any property, you will need a distinct dictionary per property.

Comment: How are you going to do an O(1) lookup for a string?  I think you mean _expected_ O(1), not _bounded_ O(1).  In other words, hashtable implementations are fair game, right?

Comment: @Wyck Yes, I am pretty much expecting some sort of hashtable implementation, where member values are keys to arrays/lists that contain matching objects. I think the biggest issue would be having separate hashtables for each member while maintaining a generic collection. I'm assuming that would mean building a dynamic type at runtime. If a collection like this exists, it would save a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Yes, you would have to do all of the maintenance of hash tables yourself, that sounds horrid. Can't you just keep these things in a database and add indexes?

Comment: You need to write a [LINQ provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/dev-tools/linq-provider-c) that can locate the indices for your collection.  And yes, it's horrid.  [Here's an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb546158(v=vs.140))

Comment: @Wyck Well, you could just write a query method rather than an entire Linq provider.

Comment: I've thought about creating a kind of indexed collection that doesn't create copies of the keys but uses lambda functions to extract the keys from the original object to use less memory than multiple `Dictionary` or `Lookup` indices, but haven't built it yet. I didn't think about query support for it, however.

Comment: Or perhaps a helper class that is an index on a lambda function over another, separate collection.

Comment: @NetMage Interesting idea. Would that be doable with value types as well? Would love to pick your brain on what your planned implementation might look like, or even collaborate on a project like this with you

Comment: @Haus I've written something for keys with duplicates - would your use case include duplicates or just unique keys?

Comment: @NetMage I wrote a proof-of-concept that uses a builder to define which properties/fields should be indexed and whether they should be unique or not. It's using nested dictionaries, hash sets and boxing though, and isn't very performant (~2 microseconds per lookup)

Comment: The only savings with a value type would be not keeping a second copy of the key, since C# doesn't really have first class references to value types (since they are intended to be immutable). My version doesn't use the built-in collections because they all keep copies of the key, which is what I am trying to avoid. What do you mean by a builder?

Comment: @Haus Mine is about 2-3x slow than `Dictionary`, but 2 microseconds seems fast, I am getting about 0.4 milliseconds for a `Dictionary` lookup.

Comment: Running further tests, it seems to me that typically the space savings is only about 4 to 8 bytes per key for the key's value (larger value type keys seems unlikely) and 12 bytes per key for the `Dictionary` overhead, at the cost of much slower creation and half the access speed. I am starting to wonder if it is worth it over `Dictionary` for most cases.

Comment: @NetMage [Here's is the proof of concept I mentioned earlier](https://pastebin.com/Di1HJjB2). Haven't had the time to look into it anymore. It _works_, but there's a lot of potential pitfalls and unchecked behavior. Very much a prototype.

Comment: @NetMage Also, [a test case to go with it](https://pastebin.com/1NrmsBv7).

Comment: `CreateGetter<>` and `GetMemberInfo` don't seem to have any definition? Your code seems terribly complex for my idea?

Comment: So I got your code working and ran it against my test harness, and I am getting 6x `Dictionary` create time, and 19x `Dictionary` lookup time, for a single `string` key, and using my somewhat poorly distributed `double` key, 7x create times and 22x lookup times.